# Send variable from one IVR to second

Tags: ivr, avaya

I want to send "call_language" variable from main IVR to second one. I am using blind transfer to connect this two IVR's. For both of them I have two different VDN's. Right now, the connection is going as illustrated in a picture. After transfer, main IVR goes to "SM"(Session Manager)  and then to "CM"(Communicatin Manager). In "CM" it looks for VDN and then goes back to "Experience Portal" through "SM", where it finds the corresponding VDN, and transfers to second IVR.
[image]
1)Is there a way to send a variable from main to second IVR?
2)Is there a way to connect these two IVR's directly, without going back to SM and CM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You stated the requirements as passing the chose language but not the whole context, so I give you my wild guesses:

1. You can have a key-value pair store. The first script sets the
   chosen language as value, the key is the UCID. The second script
   reads the value from the store with the key UCID. Since the call
   does not leave the CM the UCID should be the same for the whole
   time.
2. If the goal is to have the second script to speak the language the caller chose in the first one then you can use several VDN-s for it. For example the use chose 1 [en] then you transfer the call to VDN 2001. If the use chose 2 [de] then you transfer to 2002. For both VDNs the same script starts but it can decide which language to use.
3. You can start the second script from the first directly but you need to use hooks and some hacking in the source code so this is the most complex and needs the knowledge.